# Jquery autocomplete object passing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've cobbled together a working autocomplete prototype, which adds the selected text as a span, this works fine. What I'd like to do is call this code from elsewhere though, so I have this:

```
$("#searchBox").autocomplete({
  var testSourceData = ["First thing", "Second thing", "Third thing"];

  source: testSourceData,

  select: function(e, ui) {
    //create formatted searchTerm
    addSearchTerm(e, ui);
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  },
  ...
});

function addSearchTerm(e, ui) {
  var searchTerm = ui.item.value;
  var span = $("<span>").text(searchTerm);
  var a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({
    href: "javascript:",
    title: "Remove " + searchTerm
  }).text("x").appendTo(span);

  //add searchTerm to searchBox
  span.insertBefore("#searchBox");

}
```

My question is this; the `e` and `ui` objects, where do they get passed from?  If I want to call `addSearchTerm` from elsewhere, what do I need to pass it?

I'm currently trying to call it on the enter keypress, so I'm trying this:

```
$("#searchBox").keydown(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    addSearchTerm(event, $("#searchBox"));
  }
});
```

But I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

So I'm obviously passing it the wrong data type. I thought `$("#whatever")` referenced an object, but I guess I'm wrong.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to trigger select event

```
$("#searchBox").keydown(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
   $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {item:{value:$(this).val()}});
  }
});
```

Comment: Yup that did it, thank you!  I guess I really need to read up on how JQuery refers to things, thanks!